# Can I keep same jars with two different versions in java?

Tags: java, jar, lucene, conflict

In my web application, there is already a lucene-core jar of version 3.6.2, now to add different functionality within the same project I need latest version of lucene-core jar i.e 4.4.0.

When I replace the latest jar with previous one it throws compilation errors as backward compatibility is not maintained by Lucene.

My newly added functionality doen't work on 3.6.2 version. I know it is not possible to keep both jars version in lib. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, yes the Jar hell!

If possible move your Lucene functionalities to a separate layer such as a webservice and access this service from your web application as a webservice client. Of course, this means some sort of overhead (network etc.).

Another possibility would be to use a OSGI solution such as [JBoss Fuse](http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse) that allows to serve web applications. Move your Lucene functionalities to separate modules (each one using a different Lucene version) and import the services to your web application. The advantage is that with this solution you may access the services directly without network overhead.

Comment: I also thought of web service solution but OSGI solution looks good.I am not aware of the same. I will try for that.
thanks